# Azure CLI - Hard linking failed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I am trying to download a [Universal Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=azuredevops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) that is stored on Azure DevOps via:

```
az artifacts universal download --feed my-feed --name my-cool-package --version 1.0.0 --path Downloads
```

Inside this package is a single file `my-file.dll`.
The error I receive is:

```
Encountered an unexpected error.
System.IO.IOException: Hard linking failed!
 Status: Failed
 Path: Downloads\my-file.dll
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreClient.DownloadToFileAsync(DedupNode node, String fullPath, Uri proxyUri, EdgeCache edgeCache, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreClientWithDataport.DownloadToFileAsync(IDedupDataPort dataport, DedupNode node, String fullPath, Uri proxyUri, EdgeCache edgeCache, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupStoreClientWithDataport.DownloadToFileAsync(IDedupDataPort dataport, DedupIdentifier dedupId, String fullPath, UInt64 fileSize, GetDedupAsyncFunc dedupFetcher, Uri proxyUri, EdgeCache edgeCache, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupManifestArtifactClient.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<<DownloadAsyncWithManifestPath>b__5>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.NonSwallowingActionBlock.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<<CreateNonSwallowingFunc>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.TargetBlockExtensions.SendAllAndCompleteAsync[T1,T2](ITargetBlock`1 targetBlock, IEnumerable`1 inputs, ITargetBlock`1 finalBlock, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupManifestArtifactClient.DownloadAsyncWithManifestPath(DownloadDedupManifestArtifactOptions downloadOptions, IEnumerable`1 minimatcherFuncs, Boolean downloadManifestReferences, ISet`1 excludedPaths, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupManifestArtifactClient.DownloadSingleManifestAsync(DownloadDedupManifestArtifactOptions downloadOptions, Boolean downloadManifestReferences, ISet`1 excludedPaths, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupManifestArtifactClient.DownloadAsync(DownloadDedupManifestArtifactOptions downloadOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Packaging.UPackClientShared.UPackSharedClient.DownloadAsync(String projectNameOrId, String feedNameOrId, String packageName, String packageVersion, String targetDirectory, IEnumerable`1 minimatchPatterns, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackDownloadCommand.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in d:\a\1\s\src\ArtifactTool\Commands\UPack\UPackDownloadCommand.cs:line 60
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at ArtifactTool.Commands.UPack.UPackExceptionMapper.WithExceptionHandlingAsync(Func`1 act) in d:\a\1\s\src\ArtifactTool\Commands\UPack\UPackExceptionMapper.cs:line 39
   at ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackDownloadCommand.ExecuteAsync() in d:\a\1\s\src\ArtifactTool\Commands\UPack\UPackDownloadCommand.cs:line 64
   at ArtifactTool.Commands.CommandBase.OnExecuteAsync() in d:\a\1\s\src\ArtifactTool\Commands\CommandBase.cs:line 100
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.InvokeAsync(MethodInfo method, Object instance, Object[] arguments) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\Conventions\ExecuteMethodConvention.cs:line 77
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.OnExecute(ConventionContext context) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\Conventions\ExecuteMethodConvention.cs:line 62
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Apply>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\Conventions\ExecuteMethodConvention.cs:line 25
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.<>c__DisplayClass126_0.<OnExecute>b__0() in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.cs:line 505
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.cs:line 611
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute[TApp](CommandLineContext context) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 57
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync[TApp](CommandLineContext context) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 145
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync[TApp](IConsole console, String[] args) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 130
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync[TApp](String[] args) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 112
```

The only other instance I can find of this issue is [this Github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli-extensions/issues/554), but it did not help in resolving this issue for me.

One interesting note is that this command succeeds if I execute it by specifying `--path` to a location on the `C:\` drive.
It is failing when I execute with a path located on an external drive (e.g. `E:\`).

I have tried executing this in a Administrator PowerShell, to rule out a permissions issue, but encountered the same error.
I have also added the `--verbose --debug` arguments, but I didn't see any information that would help me dig further into this issue.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? What other suggestions do you have for me to try to get this to succeed on a drive other than `C:\`?

Comment: external, as in usb or network drive or what?

Comment: usb. Samsung SSD if that matters.

Comment: @E-rich I can reproduce your problem. Downloading the package to an external drive cannot be completed. You can report this problem on our [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21) forum.Our engineers will help you solve this problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll update this post after I get feedback on there.

Answer (score 1):

When I test downing artifact to external drive with the following az cli, I get the same error as you: `System.IO.IOException: Hard linking failed!`. Now this issue([Downloading artifact to external drive fails](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/817056/downloading-artifact-to-external-drive-fails.html)) has been reported to the product group for further investigation on Developer Community forum. If there is any progress, I will stay in sync here too.

```
cd F:\
az login in  
az artifacts universal download --organization https://dev.azure.com/xxx --feed xx --name xxx --version 1.0.0 --path .
```

[image]

Comment: This issue is closely related to the one at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67800425/azurehard-linking-failed-when-downloading-universal-packages-from-azure-devops-i/, and I've posted details about why it fails on that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Universal Artifacts require the target drive to be NTFS formatted when it tries to restore the data on Windows. The reason for this is that Universal Artifacts uses some magic under the hood to deduplicate data and minimize data transfers.

Your external drive is most likely FAT32 formatted.

Comment: And I'm not 100% sure whether Windows Home Edition includes the required features to do deduplication. It might be a Pro/Enterprise feature only.

Answer (score 0):

**edit/note:** this is not exactly the solution to the author's problem as I am not using the CLI directly.. The azure devops agent handles all the work for me.. But essentially I think that both problems might be connected, **also**, google was certain that this topic is the answer to my problem :) So here comes my solution.

**short answer**

For me, the solution was to remove the whole agent's `_work` directory with `rm -rf /home/user1/myagent/_work` command and re-deploy.

**long answer**

I had an artifact that did not contain a single subdirectory inside.. However, in my earlier attempts to make the whole artifact publishing solution to work there was in fact an artifact with a subfolder inside!

To my surprise I was able to find this same subfolder inside the folder where azure worker downloads the artifact, i.e. `/home/user1/myagent/_work/1/artifact_folder/old_sub-folder`. Apparently this is the same folder where the hard link was failing to be created.

> ##[error]Hard linking failed!
>
> Status: Failed
>
> Path: /home/user1/myagent/_work/1/artifact_folder/old_sub-folder

Therefore I think that for some reason azure dev-ops agent does not always clean up the work directory before downloading new artifacts.. I am using the newest the freshest version of the agent `vsts-agent-linux-x64-3.230.2` and the latest version of artifact download task `DownloadPipelineArtifact@2`.

If you are using the CLI as the author does - I would double check the download location and make sure that the directory is empty..